# Webview, Access camera using html5

Tags: android, webview

> Using google translator to write.

I'm using Webview to access my application.

I need to access the camera to take a photo, but I can not enable it.

My application is in a URL, where access via webview.

See my code:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
package br.com.abmprotege;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String url = "https://link-my-app";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Verifica se existe a perssão para usar a camera
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},0);
        }



        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        myWebView.loadUrl(url);


        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });


    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals(url)) {
                return false;

            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }


}
```

What do I need to do to be able to access the camera from the mobile phone through the webview?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override ***onShowFileChooser*** method of **WebChromeClient** class.

```
/**
 * Tell the client to show a file chooser.
 *
 * This is called to handle HTML forms with 'file' input type, in response to the
 * user pressing the "Select File" button.
 * To cancel the request, call <code>filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null)</code> and
 * return {@code true}.
 *
 * @param webView The WebView instance that is initiating the request.
 * @param filePathCallback Invoke this callback to supply the list of paths to files to upload,
 *                         or {@code null} to cancel. Must only be called if the
 *                         {@link #onShowFileChooser} implementation returns {@code true}.
 * @param fileChooserParams Describes the mode of file chooser to be opened, and options to be
 *                          used with it.
 * @return {@code true} if filePathCallback will be invoked, {@code false} to use default
 *         handling.
 *
 * @see FileChooserParams
 */
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
        FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
    return false;
}
```

Working example at [Github](https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp)

Comment: Zeero0, Thank you very much for your help. I'm having a question, you said to override `onShowFileChooser`, but I do not have it in my code above. What should I do?

Comment: It would be possible for you to be very kind enough to inform me what I need to do or modify in my code. Please.

Comment: I've looked at this code, but since I'm a beginner, I do not understand what I have to do. Can you help me?

Comment: I've been trying to do this since yesterday.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Copy this code https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/inf/os/fileup/MainActivity.java, link it with your activity.xml and change url

Comment: Zeero0, I did it! Thank you very much. How do I enable only the camera's photo option, without enabling the file upload option. Image: http://prntscr.com/nowdli